# Calculating weekdays issue, javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, math

i have an array of user selected days, presented as such:

```
days_selected[1] = true;
days_selected[2] = false;
days_selected[3] = false;
days_selected[4] = true;
days_selected[5] = true;
days_selected[6] = true;
days_selected[7] = true;
```

Key presents weekday, and true/false presents if the user checked the day

now, i have the current weekday,

```
date_now.getDay()
```

Lets say the current weekday is monday, 1 i need to find the amount of days between monday and the first day which is marked as true;

I know i could simply loop the days, find the current day, and keep looping until i stumble on another true day, and then subtract the values, but how do i count in day 6 being true, while day 7 and day 1 are false, in that case, it would also be 2 days in between, i am horrible at math :-)

```
passed = false;
day = 0;
$.each( days_selected, function( key, value ) {
    if (passed == true && value == true) {
        day = key;
        return false;
    }
    if (key == date_now.getDay()) {
        passed = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Would that include the current day, monday, or would you start on tuesday

Comment: if the day was monday, and tuesday was false, there would be 1 day in between monday and weensday

Comment: I would *start* by using the same values `getDay` uses for weekdays, which start at `0` (Sunday) through to `6` (Saturday).

Comment: Oh ..... well ... dont know how i missed that, my bad, thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this? (assuming indexes starting at 0)

```
var today = date_now.getDay()
  , i = today + 1;

while (i % 7 != today && !days_selected[i % 7]) {
  i += 1;
}

var interval = i - today - 1;
```

Check http://jsbin.com/jozotoke/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
function nextTrue(arr, selected, toCheck) {
    var first = arr.indexOf(toCheck, selected+1),
        res   = first > selected ? first : arr.indexOf(toCheck);
    return Math.abs(res - selected);
}
```

to be used as

```
var diff = nextTrue(days_selected, date_now.getDay(), true);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/h5wm9/2/)